# nUnit extension in the same assembly as tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

**History**: nUnit 3. I have tests with complex inheritance. A certain object is created within `SetUp` or `OneTimeSetUp`. Those methods are virtual. When this object is not closed, the leak occur.

**Problem**: The object is destroyed in `TearDown` or `OneTimeTearDown`, but those are only called when `SetUp` or `OneTimeSetUp` succeed. So when exception occurs somewhere within `TearDown` or `OneTimeTearDown`, the leak occurs. As I mentioned, there are multiple inheritance levels, so exception and critical object creation may happen in different classes, on the different stack frames.

**What I want to do**: I want to have `ITestEventListener`to react on failure before the initialization finished and clean up the critical object.

**What I tried**: *in my test assembly* I created the class:

```
namespace My.Whatever.Tests.Web.Util
{
    [Extension(EngineVersion = "3.4")]
    public class NunitEventListener : ITestEventListener
    {
        public void OnTestEvent(string report)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(report);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried running tests through

- VS (nunit 3 test adapter)
- nUnit console

None seem to load the extension.

**Question**: what am I doing wrong?

Sources of info: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Event-Listeners ,  https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Writing-Engine-Extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info about how extensions are located is found at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Engine-Extensibility#locating-addins which is linked from the second of the two references you mention.

Extensions are not searched for in your test assembly. We provided that in V2 for NUnit Addins as an easy way to test extensions, but it's a bit more complicated to do that for engine extensions. IMO it would be a good feature if we could make that work, but it involves making all extensions capable of being loaded and unloaded as new test assemblies are run. That's a major internal change to our extension service.

In the directory containing the engine assembly, you may find one or more files of type `.addins`. Whether there is one and how many and what they contain will depend on how you installed the runner and engine. That file has entries pointing to the extensions installed for that particular copy of the engine. See the above reference page for details.

In two cases, the location of extensions is more or less automatic, due to the presence of wild-card entries in the `.addins` file:

1. If you install the console runner using NuGet any extensions installed as nuget packages are found.
2. If you install the console runner using Chocolatey, any extensions installed by chocolatey are found.

In all other cases, I'm afraid that you would have to edit the `.addins` file manually.

In the specific case of the adapter, there is no `.addins` file and therefore no extensions are ever loaded. In theory, you could create such a file by hand and cause your extension to load, at least if the engine is installed in a directory to which you have access. That would be the case if you are using the nuget package. I suggest you first play with having your extension recognized under the console runner before trying this as it would involve additional complications.

BTW, not all third-party runners use the engine. If they are not using the engine at all, of course, it's not possible to provide extensions.

Update: I only just noticed your statement that `TearDown` and `OneTimeTearDown` are only run when `SetUp or`OneTimeSetUp` succeed. That's not a true statement. Both kinds of teardown only run if the corresponding setup is **run**, whether it succeeds or not. Of course, your teardowns have to be written to allow for the fact that the corresponding setup may not have run to completion, which can be tricky.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Poole, I accept this as an answer, but maybe there is any other way to subscribe to an event "test failed" as for my case? Otherwise so far the easiest thing I can see is to use AOP or do something like dynamically emit IL and patch the code in-runtime.

Comment: See update in my answer. If all you want to do is note that the test has failed, you should be able to do it in one of the teardowns. Specifically, do it in the last teardown run, which corresponds to the first setup run. I can't think of any situation where that teardown would not be run.

Comment: Hi again Mr Poole, I have validated it several times and I'm hitting the following scenario: 1) my test has OneTimeSetUp and SetUp. 2) SetUp is virtual method in base class overridden to be empty; 3) OneTimeSetup creates an object. 4) what I see in teamcity logs: "SetUp Error" pointing to my OneTimeSetup, with invalidOperationException within the object initialization, and then nothing about OneTimeTearDown being run. My oneTimeTearDown is expecting this case and would run if called (producing logs). But it wasn't.

Comment: If the error is in creating the test fixture object, then no OneTimeSetUp will have run (no matter what the log says) and therefore no OneTimeTearDown runs. OTOH if the error is inside your OneTimeSetUp (like if you instantiate some object there that is failing) the OneTimeTearDown will run.

Comment: Unless this error only shows up in TeamCity runs, you need to step outside of teamcity and actually debug through it on the desktop to really know what's going on.

Comment: Thanks :) I found the culprit with the help of your hints. One of the classes had wrong override in place and this prevented the expected OneTimeTearDown method to be called.